# Accessing the Value of a Django Queryset using a secondary list of column names

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

Im trying to avoid a hardcoding situation in my code

if have a Customer queryset for example the columns are (name,phone,email….)

so if I do

```
customer = Customer.objects.get(name = 'bbc')
# to get the values of each field I need to do

customer.name
customer.phone
customer.email
……
```

to avoid having to do this as I need to compare each field in an If statement to make a not of any changes from a form I made a list that contains the column name

Example of the if statement

```
if customer.name == some variable or customer.email == some vairiable …..
```

I made a list that contains the column name to avoid this issue

list = ['name', 'phone' , 'email']

when I do this

```
for loop 

if customer.list[i] == some variable
```

I get an error customer doesn't contain attribute list

how can I get around this issue

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use {**`getattr(..)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) here. You can replace the condition with:

```
if any(getattr(customer, li) == some_variable for li in mylist):
    # ...
```

Although it looks odd to compare all fields, which are in essence *orthogonal* dimensions, with the same variable.